# Does Chrome support multiple modules/sourceMappingURLs on a single javascript url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I have been trying out the Source Maps feature in Chrome and have found that it does not support having a single javascript resource attached to a script tag that contains multiple modules concatenated together along with a `//@sourceMappingURL` comment separating *each one*.

The first mapping is hooked up and I see the modules source associated in the debugger but all the others are ignored.

I would expect that it would be a comment requirement to do this when multiple modules are minified and concatenated together

Is scenario supported?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome DevTools does not support multiple sourceMappingURLs defined in a single file. (Pavel's answer from 2012 is incorrect unfortunately.) 
Relatedly, Chrome also does not support multiple sourceURLs in a single file.

The linked spec chapter refers to a sections array, but that's defined within a single parent map that addresses the entire file.

Therefore, if your code looks like this:

```
// ... code()

}).call(this,typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {})
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset:utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3V…  

},{"./bufferClone":99}],122:[function(require,module,exports){

// ... code()

}).call(this,typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {})
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset:utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIm5vZGVfbW9kd…
}
```

.. then you'll need to adjust your compilation pipeline so there is only a single map for your final bundled file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is supported. You can provide source maps for parts of your script using "sections" field. See [Index map: supporting post processing](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit?hl=en_US#heading=h.535es3xeprgt) section of the spec.

Comment: I might misunderstand the "Sections" feature, but I don't think this answers the question. "Sections" doesn't change that it all goes through 1 main sourceMappingURL. To clarify: what I'm after (if possible) is having a single resource that contains multiple chunks of javascript where each has their own `//@sourceMappingURL`.

Comment: @Pavel Can you give link to working example for this feature? I couldn't make to work.