# Debugging sourcmaps in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I'm having trouble getting Chrome to use an indexed source map that uses 'url' fields in the 'sections' array.

According to [Does Chrome support multiple modules/sourceMappingURLs on a single javascript url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568403/does-chrome-support-multiple-modules-sourcemappingurls-on-a-single-javascript-ur), it would seem that this is supported, but I can't seem to get it to work.
I can see Chrome fetching my source map, but it doesn't fetch any of the urls pointed to in the source map.

Are there any debugging tools available to try and figure out what the problem is.  I previously was generating invalid json for the source map but Chrome didn't complain or output any errors or warnings to the console.

Is there some place else in Chrome that I can look for errors related to parsing or processing source maps?

Here's my source map:

```
{
    "version" : 3,
    "file" : "app.js",
    "sections" : [
        {"offest" : {"line":17, "column":89}, "url":"./_sourcemap/dojo/cldr/nls/en/gregorian.map"},
        {"offest" : {"line":22, "column":555}, "url":"./_sourcemap/dijit/Calendar.map"},
        {"offest" : {"line":30, "column":66}, "url":"./_sourcemap/dojo/date.map"},
        {"offest" : {"line":34, "column":213}, "url":"./_sourcemap/dojo/date/locale.map"},
        {"offest" : {"line":47, "column":301}, "url":"./_sourcemap/dojo/cldr/supplemental.map"},
        {"offest" : {"line":49, "column":139}, "url":"./_sourcemap/dojo/cldr/nls/gregorian.map"},
        {"offest" : {"line":58, "column":470}, "url":"./_sourcemap/dijit/CalendarLite.map"},
        {"offest" : {"line":70, "column":1965}, "url":"./_sourcemap/dijit/form/DropDownButton.map"}
    ]
}
```